# Ajax GET response from PHP cross domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Trying to get a response from a php which is on another domain, I've addded datatype:"jsonp" but I think the server needs to be changed. The format in which the repsonse is received is like so:

response=1

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType : "jsonp",
                data: "email="+emailaddress+"&country="+'DE'+"&lang="+lang+"&source="+'Aufrufzeitpunkt',
                url: "promo_getstate.php",
            }).done(function(data){
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(obj);

            });
```

In chrome I get the following messsage:
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:

I don't get any message in Firefox

Is there anyway I can fix this without having to change anything on the server?

Comment: That's doesn't seems like cross domain : your url is relative

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: I didn't include the full url, for privacy

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.get("promo_getstate.php",{
    email:emailaddress,
    country:'DE',
    lang:lang,
    source:'Aufrufzeitpunkt'
},function(data){
   console.log(data);
},"JSON");
```

Comment: doesn't work says Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.